# Getting index out of range exception if cell is empty in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, list, datatable

I am reading a Excel file with 60 columns. Problem is if the cell is empty it just throws index out of range exception and if cell contains some data then it reads the value. Any idea how can I read the empty cell. I am using the following code to do so. It works fine for empty cells for other types of data but these cells contain date values.

```
List<string> depDates = new List<string>();
        for (int j = 54; j < 58; j++)
        {
            if (tableData.DataRows[0][j] == string.Empty)
            {
                depDates.Add("null");
            }
            else
            {
                depDates.Add(tableData.DataRows[0][j]);
            }
        }
```

The format of these columns in Excel is Text. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
  if (tableData.DataRows[0][j] == null ||tableData.DataRows[0][j].Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            depDates.Add("null");
        }
```

Comment: what about white spaces? Any case `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` and `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()` are designed for this purpose.

Comment: I think if there is white space it will be different of `null`.

Comment: exactly, it will not be `null` and it will not be `string.Empty`. you'll end up adding something like `" "` to collection of `depDates`. and that is why I've used `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` to answer this question

Answer (score 1):

Possibly there are whitespaces in cells, check cells like following:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(tableData.DataRows[0][j])) ...
```